# Difficult Integral involving $\tan^2x$

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

How can we evaluate this difficult integral:

> $$\int\frac{\tan^2x}{1-x\tan^2x}dx=\int\frac{1}{\cot^2x-x}dx$$

I tried using integration by parts but I suppose it doesn't work with this.

In the worst case, if this integral doesn't have a closed formula, how can we $prove$ that it cannot be found?

Comment: I doubt it would have a closed form

Comment: You [can't](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(tan%5E2+x)%2F(1-xtan%5E2+x)).

Comment: Do you really need to find an explicit antiderivative of $\frac{1}{\cot^2 x-x}$, or the original question is about the evaluation of a definite integral?

Comment: My question was just to find the explicit antiderivate.

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting to note that your integral telescopes, starting with

$$\int\frac{\tan^2x}{1-x\tan^2x}dx=\int\frac{\tan^2x}{1-x\tan^2x}\frac{(1+x\tan^2x)}{(1+x\tan^2x)}dx$$

Next multiply top and bottom by $1+x^2\tan^4x$ and so on. In this process the denominator tends to 1 (assuming the integral is between the limits of $x=0$ and $x=\pi/4$) and the numerator to the infinite series $S$

$$S=\tan^2 x+x\tan^4 x+x^2\tan^6x+x^3\tan^8x+x^4\tan^{10}x+...$$

Now anybody who claims there is a nice closed form to be found can be given the task of integrating these terms one by one until all faith in this proposition runs dry.

I understand that this is not a proof, but all you asked for was a way of demonstrating the difficulty with this integral.